How is the expected value 1/p
A Markov Decision Process
There is an MDP with 2 states that are $s_1$ and $s_2$. The reward for moving to $s_1$ is $1$ with a probability of $1-p$ whereas it's $0$ for $s_2$ with $p$ probability. In the provided image link there is the model.
Now this is a model free reinforcement learning problem. We are asked to evaluate First Visit Monte Carlo and Every Visit Monte Carlo. The image shows the solutions that leave me very confused. If the states in the episode
is $\{s_1,s_1,...,s_1,s_2\}$ then the image implies that $X$ is a geometric random variable with an expectation of $\frac{1}{p}$.
Let me assume that $X$ is the number of visits done to state $1$ before transitioning to the terminal state which is state $2$.
Let me take the episode $\{s_1,s_1,s_2\}$. Then for both first visited $s_1$ and every visited $s_1$ the total return becomes $\hat{V}(s_1)=1$.
So when $X=2$ the prediction for the value of the state is $1$.
Then one can conclude that for any episode in first visited $s_1$: $$\hat{V}(s_1)=X-1$$
For every visited $s_1$: $$\hat{V}(s_1)=\frac{1}{X-1}\sum_{i=1}^{X-1}(X-i)=\frac{X}{2}$$
So from the paper itself $X$ has to be at least $2$ otherwise value of the state is undefined.
Now let me write a geometric sum whose result is $\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{p}$.
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=p\hspace{0.1cm}+2(1-p)p+3(1-p)^2p\hspace{0.1cm}+\hspace{0.1cm}...$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp(1-p)^{k-1}$$
Now this seems familiar. This is a weighted geometric sum that has the result:
$$\frac{p}{(1-(1-p))^2}=\frac{p}{p^2}=\frac{1}{p}\hspace{0.2cm}given\hspace{0.2cm}1-p<1$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{p}$$
From now on the paper continued with this result. But if we look at the first term in summation it is $p$.
The way I see it is that first term means the probability of transitioning to the terminal state.
But in the derivation of the value of every visited $s_1$ I see that $s_1$ has to be visited at least once.
Then the summation becomes:$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}kp(1-p)^{k-1}$$
If $X=2$, $s_1$ is visited once before moving to the terminal state which is given by:
$$(1-p)p$$
If $X=3$, $s_1$ is visited twice before moving to the terminal state. Probability of this is:
$$(1-p)(1-p)p$$
Now obviously the expectation of $X$ will be their summation with the corresponding $X$ value.
$$if\hspace{0.3cm}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp(1-p)^{k-1}=\frac{1}{p}$$ $$then\hspace{0.3cm}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}kp(1-p)^{k-1}=\frac{1}{p}-p=\frac{1-p}{p^2}$$
So as a result if $s_1$ is visited at least once then $\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1-p}{p^2}$
But if $s_1$ doesn't have to be visited at least once and immediate transition to $s_2$ happens with $p$ probability $\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{p}$
What am I missing here? Are my calculations true?
